# masonry.js div reset when select link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey so here's the website I'm working http://trevormsmith.com/linx/art.html

Trying to build a filter system (in the footer), and when you click on the specific categories (minimalist, typographic, abstract) masonry resets the images into a single column, instead of the grid. If you resize the browser, it'll readjust to normal.

This is what I have calling masonry to the containers with the images

Also, when I set the #minimalist, #typographic, #abstract to display:show instead of display:none (which it needs to be), the layout is fine and it works smoothly.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: So here's the code that is working only for #minimalist, except the masonry is not being triggered and the images stay floated instead of tiling:

**EditEdit:** here's the current code, #containers fade in as a single column instead of grid layout: http://jsfiddle.net/T6SDb/1/

Calling the masonry:

```
$( function() {

$('#container-all, #minimalist, #typographic, #abstract').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item, .item-m, .item-t, .item-a',
    columnWidth: 7 }); });
```

And then the fadein/fadeout for the filter:

```
$('#btn-all').click(function(e){    
$('#minimalist, #typographic').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#container-all').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow', function(){
    });
});});
$('#btn-m').click(function(e){    
$('#container-all, #typographic').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#minimalist').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow', function(){
        $('#container-all').masonry('layout');
    });
}); });
$('#btn-t').click(function(e){    
$('#container-all, #minimalist').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#typographic').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow', function(){
        $('#container-all').masonry('layout');
    });
}); });
$('#btn-a').click(function(e){    
$('#container-all, #typographic, #minimalist').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#abstract').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow', function(){
        $('#container-all').masonry('layout');
    });
}); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling masonary('layout') after fading in the selected images, i.e. for the container-all (from your filter.js file) try this:

```
$('#btn-all').click(function(e){    
    $('#minimalist, #typographic').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#container-all').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow', function(){
            $('#container-all').masonry('layout');
        });
    });
});
```

I'm only testing this from the JavaScript console so you might need to tweak the timing / positioning. I'm doing it when the fade is complete, you might want to try doing just after the start of the fade.

**Edit**

It may be because of the way your containers are put together and how you start masonary, perhaps you can do this in your main source:

```
var mason;
$( function() {
    mason = $('#container-all, #minimalist, #typographic, #abstract').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item, .item-m, .item-t, .item-a',
            columnWidth: 7});
        });
});
```

Then later you can use `mason.masonary('layout')` in each of your click functions rather than referring to a single container, i.e. for the first one try:

```
$('#btn-all').click(function(e){    
    $('#minimalist, #typographic').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#container-all').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow', function(){
             mason.masonary('layout');
        });
    });
});
```

Depending when you want things to appear and rearrange you might want to fadeTo a certain value then do the layout and then complete the fade (or you could do that on a delay too).

Maybe look at the Masonary functions `hide` and `reveal` to remove given elements.

It may also make things easier to work with the items themselves rather than the containers (since everything gets rearranged) and just have one outside container for everything.

I'd also suggest trying a simpler example (maybe just colored `div`s or something), working with that, and posting it if you still have issues. There may be some interaction between the libraries you are using.

**Edit 2**

Added [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/2QhVe/3), that uses the separate `mason` variable above. It works but, again, you might need to do something about the timing of the fade in / fade out -- of course you can't arrange the things until they're visible which is an issue. I'm not sure of the best way to fix that.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked only for #minimalist, however in only setting the images in the right layout instead of the column, except the masonry is not being triggered and they stay floated instead of tiling. @SpaceDog

Comment: It worked for me, basically `.masonary('layout')` is what is trigged on a resize so it should be the same, but perhaps it's because of the containers, I've added a bit to the answer.

Comment: (http://jsfiddle.net/T6SDb/1/) for better look. When clicked on categories, images go into column layout. (ignore captions in the background) @SpaceDog

Comment: Wow must of had something missing, swapped the code out and works like a charm. Thanks for the help! @SpaceDog